# There's no syntax error but php returns error

Tags: php, parsing

In following code, php returns:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www_lab\tablo\test.php on line 13

But I can't see any wrong in code.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$db_select = mysql_select_db("table",$conn);

if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = $_GET['q'];

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (`email` LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$q."%')");

    if (mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) { // if one or more rows are returned do following
            while ( $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) ) {
                echo "<p><h3>".$results['name']."</h3>".$results['surname']."</p>";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said there's while loop begins in that line.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: can you show full error message ?

Comment: can you post the how file and error please ? the code you posted does not have any error in it

Comment: The `curly braces {}` are not aligned proper manner, Please check it `open and closed curly braces` are completed from top to bottom of the page.

Comment: @Ranjith That would not cause any error.. at all.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wN4cgbeF - error is:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\_lab\tablo\test.php on line 13

Comment: @Daedalus : In this code, everything is fine. Suppose if he neglecting some of code for this posting means...? . I just noticed to him that kind of awareness.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @NullPonyPointer I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, given what the code was and what it appeared to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your actual code file, the following answer is shooting in the dark;

.. Getting onto it, however, it would appear that you copied this code from an external source, such as something like jsfiddle or some blog.  The point here, is that sometimes when such copies are made, there are hidden characters in the text of that copy.

The presence of this hidden character usually always breaks any code on that line, especially in php.

.. And here is my recommendation for you.  Delete the entire line 13.  Re-type it out from scratch.  If your problem still persists, that is not the issue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wN4cgbeF - error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www_lab\tablo\test.php on line 13

Comment: @lmrahil There is nothing wrong with that paste.  Please actually attempt my answer.  I should add that a paste-bin is not 'access to the file'.  I would need the actual file in that case.

Comment: Yep, looks like it's hiddec char issue. I re-type everything and it's fixed.